# Creating a SQL query using selectinput in R shiny

Tags: r, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to create a dynamic query using select input.

Something like

Select * from basket where fruits in("apple","banana","cherry")

I have a table called fruit_list which populates my selectinput box.

selectInput("fruit_list", label = h5("Select fruit"), multiple = T, choices = (dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT fruit from fruit_list');")))

So far, when i renderprint my selection I get "apple" "banana" "cherry"
I need a comma between the elements to get "apple","banana","cherry"
When i choose a single element from the multiselect box "apple"

Select * from basket where fruits in("apple")

my application runs perfectly. However, when i select more than one element "apple" "banana" I get an error: Expecting a single string value: [type=character; extent=2].

I apologize for not being as explicit in the beginning

Comment: The `paste` command can be used to concatenate an SQL query string together

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `ans` is a non-empty subset of `c("a", "b", "c", "d")` .  For example,

```
ans <- c("b", "d")
sprintf("select * from table where item in (%s)", toString(shQuote(ans, "csh")))
```

giving:

```
[1] "select * from table where item in ('b', 'd')"
```

If you are using R 3.6 or later you can optionally replace the `shQuote(ans, "csh")` with `sQuote(ans, FALSE)` .

If `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` in the question were supposed to represent numbers then we don't need the quotes so we can replace `toString(...)` with just `toString(ans)` .

No packages are used.

Answer (score 0):

`selectInput` takes in user input as a character vector, `glue` should be more easier to use when your query is more complex.

```r
library(glue)
# user_input <- input$selectInput # e.g. c("a","b","c","d")
user_input <- c("a","b","c","d")
sql_where <- paste0(user_input,collapse = ", ")
glue("select * from table where item in ({sql_where})")
```

It translates into:

```r
select * from table where item in (a, b, c, d)
```