# How to create a dynamic query using select input

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, shiny-reactivity, shinyapps

I am trying to create a dynamic query using select input.

Something like

```
Select * from basket where fruits in("apple","banana","cherry")
```

I have a table called fruit_list which populates my selectinput box.

```
selectInput("fruit_list", label = h5("Select fruit"), multiple = T, 
  choices = (dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT fruit from fruit_list');")))
```

So far, when i renderprint my selection I get "apple" "banana" "cherry"
I need a comma between the elements to get "apple","banana","cherry"
When i choose a single element from the multiselect box "apple"

```
Select * from basket where fruits in("apple")
```

my application runs perfectly. However, when i select more than one element "apple" "banana" I get an error: Expecting a single string value: [type=character; extent=2].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a SQL query using selectinput in R shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58066371/creating-a-sql-query-using-selectinput-in-r-shiny)

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Show more exactly what code is being run.

Answer (score 0):

`paste('dbGetQuery(conn,"Select fruit from fruits;", collapse =', '))`

Comment: This opens the app up to many security vulnerabilities such as SQL injection. Please do not do this. Better options suggested by @yifyan in the comments above.

Comment: uh, didn't know that. Quite interesting, could you give me some details on the security vulnerabilities.